# How to round and format a number in JavaScript without trailing zeros?

Tags: javascript, jquery, numbers, number-formatting, trailing

I have two inputs that get multiplied and I need the result to be rounded down without trailing zeros. I have tried a few different built-in methods, such as `number.toFixed(2)`, but they did not produce the desired result.

This issue can be reproduced by typing the numbers 20 and 6 into the first and second inputs here:

```js
$(document).on("change", ".p-cell, .s-cell", () => {
    var val1 = $(".p-cell").val();
    var val2 = $(".s-cell").val();    
    var total = val1 / 100 * val2;
    
    $(".w-cell").val(total).trigger("input");
});
```

```html
<input class="p-cell" type="text" value="0" />
<input class="s-cell" type="text" value="0" />
<input class="w-cell" type="text" value="0" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Number.prototype.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed), `.toFixed(2)` if you want to show two decimals:

```js
const $pCell = $(".p-cell");
const $sCell = $(".s-cell");
const $wCell = $(".w-cell");

$(document).on('input', '.p-cel, .s-cell', () => {
  const val1 = $pCell.val() || 0;
  const val2 = $sCell.val() || 0;
  const total = (val1 / 100 * val2).toFixed(2);
    
  $wCell.val(total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="p-cell" type="text" value="0" />
<input class="s-cell" type="text" value="0" />
<input class="w-cell" type="text" value="0" readonly />
```

Additionally, if you want to remove any number of trailing zeroes, so `1.20` becomes `1.2` and `2.00` becomes `2`, you could use [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions): `total.replace(/\.?0+$/, '')`:

```js
const $pCell = $(".p-cell");
const $sCell = $(".s-cell");
const $wCell = $(".w-cell");

$(document).on('input', '.p-cel, .s-cell', () => {
  const val1 = $pCell.val() || 0;
  const val2 = $sCell.val() || 0;
  const total = (val1 / 100 * val2).toFixed(2);
    
  $wCell.val(total.replace(/\.?0+$/, ''));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="p-cell" type="text" value="0" />
<input class="s-cell" type="text" value="0" />
<input class="w-cell" type="text" value="0" readonly />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rounding without trailing zero with `Math.round`. Here I give you a trick of it.

```js
        $(document).on("change", ".p-cell, .s-cell", function () {
    var val1 = $(".p-cell").val();
    var val2 = $(".s-cell").val();
    var total = Math.round((val1/100 * val2)*100)/100;
    $(".w-cell").val(total).trigger("input");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="p-cell" type="text" value="0" />
    <input class="s-cell" type="text" value="0" />
    <input class="w-cell" type="text" value="0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several common ways to round to a fixed number of decimal places in JavaScript. Each one has certain problems.

**Number.protototype.toFixed method**

```
Number(x).toFixed(digits)
```

This method produces a string with the requested number of digits. However it rounds numbers that end in 5 incorrectly about 9% of the time.

**Multiply-then-divide method**

```
Math.round( x * (10 ** digits) ) / (10 ** digits);
```

This produces a number rounded to `digits`, but it rounds incorrectly about 0.7% of the time.

**exponent add-and-subtract method**

```
Math.round( x + 'e' + digits ) + 'e-' + digits;
```

This produces a number rounded to `digits`, and rounds correctly. But it has a fatal flaw—for input values smaller than 1e-6, it returns `NaN`.

I've written a function that uses the exponent add-and-subtract method, but it avoids the fatal error for small input values. Available on [github](https://github.com/terrymorse58/round-tofixed).

```js
/**
 * round number `x` to `digits` number of digits after decimal point
 */
function roundToFixed (val, digits = 0) {
  if (typeof val === 'number' && typeof digits === 'number'
    && Number.isInteger(digits) &&
    (digits === 0 || Math.sign(digits) === 1)) {
    const valF = numToFloat(val);
    const valFNew = numToFloat(
      Math.round(+(valF.mant + 'e' + (valF.exp + digits)))
    );
    return +(valFNew.mant + 'e' + (valFNew.exp - digits));
  }
  return NaN;
}

/**
 * convert number to Float object
 */
function numToFloat (val) {
  const [mant, exp] = Number(val)
    .toExponential()
    .split('e')
    .map(str => +str);
  return {
    mant,
    exp
  };
}
```